# Problem to trigger functions/sendmail with sendgrid in react(endpoint /.netlify/functions/sendmail not found 404)

Tags: reactjs, formik, netlify, netlify-function, netlify-cli

Im trying to send emails from my react web application via netlify functions and I can not trigger the handler of my sendmail.js which is in my functions folder. I´m always getting the same error http:localhost:8080/(here I tried a lot of routes like “.netlify/functions/sendemail”) error 404 not found.

here are my folders, as you can see functions folder is now inside of src folder, but I tried to place it in the root directory and anything the console gives me the same error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XrVwc.png)

here is a screenshot of the error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aywzv.png)

I´m trying to send values after a captcha is validated, I made a form with formik and I add all the atribbutes as the documentAtion says

here is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.3/dist/leaflet.css"
     integrity="sha256-kLaT2GOSpHechhsozzB+flnD+zUyjE2LlfWPgU04xyI="
     crossorigin=""/>
     <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.3/dist/leaflet.js"
     integrity="sha256-WBkoXOwTeyKclOHuWtc+i2uENFpDZ9YPdf5Hf+D7ewM="
     crossorigin=""></script>
    <title>Clínica Pal Dental</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form method="POST" name="contact-form" data-netlify="true" netlify-honeypot="bot-field" hidden>
      <input type="text" name="NameSurname" />
      <input type="text" name="Phone" />
      <input type="text" name="Email" />
      <textarea name="Comment"></textarea>
      <input type="checkbox" name="LegalConsent" />
      <input name="bot-field" type="hidden" />
    </form>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

heres is the formik with the useEffect after the captcha is validated

```
useEffect(() =>{
        async function sendEmailNetlify(){
            
            await fetch(`/.netlify/functions/sendmail`,
            {
                method : "POST", 
                data : formValues
            })
            .then(({ response }) =>{
                debugger;
                alert(JSON.stringify(response))
            })
            .catch(error =>{
                console.log(JSON.parse(error))
            })
            
        }
        if(isCaptchaSent){
            sendEmailNetlify();
        }
    }, [formValues, isCaptchaSent]);

    return(
        <div className="modal fade" id="ContactModal" tabIndex="-1" aria-labelledby="ContactModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div className="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
                <div className="modal-content">
                    <div className="modal-header justify-content-end">
                        <button type="button" className="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                    </div>
                    <Formik 
                        initialValues={initialContactFormValues} 
                        validationSchema={validationSchema}
                        onSubmit={handleSubmitValues}>
                        {({ resetForm }) => {
                            return(
                                <Form 
                                    id="contactForm" 
                                    name="contact-form"
                                    data-netlify="true"
                                    data-netlify-honeypot="bot-field"
                                    data-netlify-recaptcha="true"
                                    noValidate
                                >
                                    <Field type="hidden" name="bot-field" />
                                    <Field type="hidden" name="form-name" />
                                    <div className="modal-body d-flex flex-column justify-content-start align-items-center mt-n4">
                                        <h5 className="modal-title" id="ContactModalLabel">Contacto</h5>
                                        <h3>Introduce tus datos</h3>
                                        
                                        <div className="form-group">
                                            <label className="form-group__label" htmlFor="NameSurname">
                                                Nombre y apellidos <span className="mandatory">*</span>
                                            </label>
                                            <Field id="NameSurnameInput" name="NameSurname" className="form-group__input"/>
                                            <ErrorMessage name="NameSurname" className="form-group__error" component="span"/>
                                        </div>

                                        <div className="form-group">
                                            <label className="form-group__label" htmlFor="Phone">
                                                Teléfono <span className="mandatory">*</span>
                                            </label>
                                            <div className="input-group flex-nowrap">
                                                <Field id="phoneInput" name="Phone" className="form-group__input"/>
                                                <i className="input-group-text icon icon-info" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="bottom" title="El teléfono no puede contener espacios, tampoco es necesario el prefijo" data-bs-custom-class="custom-tooltip"></i>
                                            </div>
                                            <ErrorMessage name="Phone" className="form-group__error" component="span"/>
                                        </div>

                                        <div className="form-group">
                                            <label className="form-group__label" htmlFor="Email">
                                                Email <span className="mandatory">*</span>
                                            </label>
                                            <Field id="emailInput" name="Email" className="form-group__input"/>
                                            <ErrorMessage name="Email" className="form-group__error" component="span"/>
                                        </div>

                                        <div className="form-group">
                                            <label className="form-group__label" htmlFor="Comment">
                                                Comentario <span className="mandatory">*</span>
                                            </label>
                                            <div className="comment">
                                                <Field as="textarea" id="commentInput" name="Comment" className="form-group__input" rows="5"/>
                                            </div>
                                            <ErrorMessage name="Comment" className="form-group__error" component="span" />
                                        </div>

                                        <div className="form-group__legal px-3">
                                            <div className="legal__container">
                                                <Field type="checkbox" id="legalConsentInput" name="LegalConsent" />
                                                <p>He leido y acepto las condiciones de <Link to="/terminos-legales" target="_blank">Aviso Legal</Link> y <Link to="/terminos-legales" target="_blank">Política de privacidad</Link></p>
                                            </div>
                                            <ErrorMessage name="LegalConsent" className="form-group__error ps-0" component="span"/>
                                        </div>
                                        <Reaptcha
                                            ref={rcRef}
                                            sitekey={process.env.RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY}
                                            data-netlify-recaptcha="true"
                                            onError={onError}
                                            onExpire={onExpire}
                                            onVerify={onVerify}
                                            onLoad={() => onLoad(() => resetForm)}
                                            size="invisible"
                                        />
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="modal-footer justify-content-center">
                                        {renderSubmitButtonState(isSubmitting, executing, verified)}
                                    </div>
                                </Form>
                            )
                        }}
                    </Formik>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
```

heres is my netlify.toml

```
[[redirects]]
    from = "/*"
    to = "/index.html"
    status = 200

[dev]
  command = "npm start"
  port = 8080
  targetPort = 3000
  publish = "./src/bundles"
  functions = "./src/functions"

[build]
  publish = "./src/bundles"
  functions = "./src/functions"

[functions]
  # Directory with serverless functions, including background
  # functions, to deploy. This is relative to the base directory
  # if one has been set, or the root directory if
  # a base hasn’t been set.
  directory = "./src/functions"
  node_bundler = "esbuild"
```

here is my sendmail.js

```
const client = require('@sendgrid/mail');
const {
  SENDGRID_API_KEY,
  SENDGRID_TO_EMAIL,
  SENDGRID_FROM_EMAIL,
} = process.env;

exports.handler = async function (event, context, callback) {
  debugger;
  const { message, senderEmail, senderName } = JSON.parse(event.body);
  client.setApiKey(SENDGRID_API_KEY);

  const data = {
    to: SENDGRID_TO_EMAIL,
    from: SENDGRID_FROM_EMAIL,
    subject: `New message from ${senderName} (${senderEmail})`,
    html: message,
  };

  try {
    await client.send(data);
    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: 'Message sent',
    };
  } catch (err) {
    return {
      statusCode: err.code,
      body: JSON.stringify({ msg: err.message }),
    };
  }
};
```

Im trying to send emails from my application, please can someone help to get it, I´m desperate